# javascript loop class changes with timing and CSS keyframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have these two paragraph tags within a div. One paragraph falls from the top of the div, stays for a moment, then falls out of view. The other starts a scale 0,0 and grows to 1,1. Each of these are timed with `keyframes` in the `CSS`. The desired effect is that the first one falls, does it's thing, then after it falls out of the element, the second one grows into view, does its thing, then all repeats.

I can't figure out how to do this. `CSS` doesn't allow changing display to "none" in `keyframe` settings and if i don't `display:none` it, then the two present elements throw each other off.

I've tried to create a `jquery` loop that just infinitely alters the classes but I'm having a hard time getting this. Right now, the first iteration is perfect. The first

falls, stays, then moves on. The second

grows, does it's thing, then moves on. But I can't get it to repeat.

```
   @keyframes animate1 {

    10% {
    transform: translateY(0px);

  }
             20% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
             90% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
             100% {
    transform: translateY(300px);

  }

}
         @keyframes animate2 {
    16% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
             80%{
                 transform: scale(.85, .85);
             }
             90%{
                 transform: scale(.85, .85);
                 transform: translateY(0px);
             }
             100% {
                 transform: translateY(300px);
             }
        }

 #animate1{
            transform: translateY(-300px);


        }

        .hidden{
            display: none;
        }
        .animated1{
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            animation: animate1;
            animation-duration: 2.5s;
          animation-direction: normal;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;

        }

        #animate2{
            transform: scale(0,0);


        }

        .animated2{
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            animation: animate2;
            animation-duration: 2.5s;
          animation-direction: normal;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;

        }
```

Then followed by:

```
<p id="animate1" class="hidden">I'm paragraph 1, I fall down</p>
<p id="animate2" class="hidden">I'm paragraph 2, i grow big</p>
```

and the jquery:

```
    var one = $("#animate1");
    var two = $("#animate2");

function animate() {

    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++){
        two.removeClass('animated2');
        two.addClass('hidden');
        one.removeClass('hidden');
        one.addClass('animated1');

        setInterval(function(){
            one.removeClass('animated1');
            one.addClass('hidden');
            two.toggleClass('animated2');
        }, 2500)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is how i ended up doing it. I created a function that runs onload and attached it to the body. then I just changed my css classes and pointed to another function at the end of the changes. then at the end of that other funciton, i pointed back to the previous one, essentially creating a loop.

```
function initiate(){
          one.toggleClass('animated1');
        setTimeout(switchOne, 3500);

          }

          function switchOne(){
              one.removeClass('animated1');
              one.addClass('hidden');
              two.removeClass('hidden');
              two.addClass('animated2');
              setTimeout(switchTwo, 3500);

          }

          function switchTwo(){
             two.removeClass('animated2');
              two.addClass('hidden');
              one.removeClass('hidden');
              one.addClass('animated1');
              setTimeout(switchOne, 3500);
          }
```